# Bower: How to skip (ignore) some files in downloaded packages

Tags: javascript, bower

Is it possible to config bower in a way that it does not download some specific files or folders? For example I minify `.js` files myself so I don't need `.min.js` files. Such files make my IDE (PHPStorm) confused in finding the source code of functions and also make code indexing process inefficient. [bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer) seems to be a solution, however, I prefer to use `bower` itself.

Comment: I don't use an IDE, but know those issues in Sublime with all those libs and already processed files you don't want to see. So if this is just about indexing, I'd recommend ignoring the `bower_components` or `lib` folder in your project (and any other folders not containing *your* source files). Sublime has a option called `folder_exclude_patterns` for that. Your IDE might have some switch, too.

Comment: @naeramarth7 Indexing relevant files in `boser_components` folder is really necessary. And manually excluding some files/folders in it is wearisome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a bower package you can specify what files will be ignored. For example:

`{
        "name": "YourAwesomePackageName",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "main": "dist/your-awesome-js-module.js",
        "ignore": [
            "source",
            "spec",
            ".bowerrc",
            ".gitignore",
            ".jshintignore",
            ".jshintrc",
            "bower.json",
            "gruntfile.js",
            "package.json",
            "README.md"
        ],
        "dependencies": {
            "jquery": ">=1.10.2",
            "underscore": "~1.5.2"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "jquery-mockjax": "~1.5.2"
        }
    }`

Source: http://bob.yexley.net/creating-and-maintaining-your-own-bower-package/